# Json data extraction is not workinggood

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, visual-studio-2010

h experts,

i have a .netservice which returs json data and i extracted the json data using the code

```
success: function (r) {
        var doclist = $.parseJSON(r.d);
        console.log(doclist);
```

i got the out put like this

```
{"status":{"status":"success","userid":"1"},"data":{"docId":9,"doc_name":"Array","file_name":"Admin/ch6_macro_processors.pdf","owneruser":1,"cat_id":1,"desctiption":"jkkkl","comments":"fghh","dept_id":1,"contype":"application/pdf","size":0,"rvwFlg":"application/pdf","right":"R"},"data":{"docId":10,"doc_name":"Image","file_name":"Admin/545765_427770260634015_1210695556_n.jpg","owneruser":1,"cat_id":1,"desctiption":"control so users can upload files on the site that i've built. The location I'm attempting to save t","comments":"control so users can upload files on the site that i've built. The location I'm attempting to save t","dept_id":1,"contype":"image/jpeg","size":127,"rvwFlg":"image/jpeg","right":"R"},"data":{"docId":9,"doc_name":"Array","file_name":"Admin/ch6_macro_processors.pdf","owneruser":1,"cat_id":1,"desctiption":"jkkkl","comments":"fghh","dept_id":1,"contype":"application/pdf","size":0,"rvwFlg":"application/pdf","right":"U"}}
```

but

```
console.log(doclist.data["docId"]); retuns error
```

" Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'docId' of undefined "

How o read this docId

i am using visual studio 2010 and frame work 3.5

regards,

Sivajith s.

Comment: What is the output you posted? The result of the web service call or the value of `r.d`? There is no wrapper `d` property in the thing you posted.

Comment: i mentiond its "doclist"

Answer (score 1):

Check out my example [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YDJGE/1/)

Your issue is your not accessing the inner object.
Assuming r is the json string.

```
var doclist = $.parseJSON(r.d); // Service wraps the data in r.d
console.log(doclist);
alert(docList.data.docId);
```

Comment: when i run it using visual studio i got this error.....and now also it remains same....i got console.log(doclist) and never get doclist.data or doclist.data.docId